# Create a piecewise smooth function which preserves local integrals from data

Tags: python, math, pandas, scipy, statistics

I'm a PhD student in sociology working on my dissertation. In the course of some data analysis, I have bumped up against the following problem.

I have a table of measured values of some variable over a series of years. The values count, *"how many events of a certain type there are in a given year"?* Here is a sample of what it looks like:

```
year    var
1983    22
1984    55
1985    34
1986    29
1987    15
1988    20
1989    41
```

So, e.g. in 1984, 55 such events occured over the whole year.

One way to represent this data over the domain of real numbers in [1983, 1990) is with a piecewise function `f`:

```
f(x) = var if floor(x) == year, for all x in [1983, 1990).
```

This function plots a series of horizontal lines of width 1, mapping a bar chart of the variable. The area under each of these lines is equal to the variable's value in that year. However, for this variable, I know that in each year, the rate is not constant over the whole year. In other words, the events don't suddenly jump from one yearly rate to another rate overnight on Dec 31, as the (discontinuous) function `f` seems to present. I don't know exactly how the rate changes, but I'd like to assume a smooth transition from year to year.

So, what I want is a function `g` which is both continuous and smooth (continuously differentiable) over the domain [1983, 1990), *which also preserves the yearly totals.* That is, the definite integral of `g` from 1984 to 1985 must still equal 55, and same for all other years. (So, for example, an n-degree polynomial which hits all the midpoints of the bars will NOT work.) Also, I'd like `g` to be a piecewise function, with all the pieces relatively simple -- quadratics would be best, or a sinusoid.

In sum: I want `g` to be a series of parabolas defined over each year, which smoothly transition from one to the other (left and right limits of `g'(x)` should be equal at the year boundaries), and where the area under each parabola is equal to the totals given by my data above.

[I've drawn a crude version of what I want here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvSjj.jpg) The cartoon uses the same data as above, with the black curve representing my hoped-for function, `g`. Toward the right end things got particularly bad, esp 1988 and 1989. But it's just meant to show a picture of what I would like to end up with.

Thanks for your help, or for pointing me towards other resources you think might be helpful!

PS I have looked at [this paper](http://journals.ametsoc.org/doi/abs/10.1175/1520-0485%281996%29026%3C0136%3ATIOFFI%3E2.0.CO%3B2) which is linked inside [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342064/curve-fitting-with-known-integrals-python) I agree with the authors (see section 4) that if I could replace my data with pseudodata d' using matrix A, from which I could very simply generate some sort of smooth function, that would be great, but they do not say how A could be obtained. Just some food for thought. Thanks again!

PPS What I need is a reliable method of generating g, given ANY data table as above. I actually have hundreds of these kinds of yearly count data, so I need a general solution.

Comment: My question to you: is this really the best representation for your data? When you want to show the data the graph you'll plot makes me think that the data is really a smooth function, when it isn't. When you want to model the underlying function, drawing a curve that just fits the data won't be good enough, as there are infinite functions that fulfill the requirements. Either way, just drawing a function like the one you ask for isn't optimal for a dissertation, imo

Comment: I would like to clarify something, just to be sure. With g(x) being the value at x given from your table and and H(x,y) being the definite integral of from x to y derived from some g(x)-data-fitting function h(x), you want g(x) = H(x,x+1). Is this correct?

Comment: @WorldSEnder: Thanks for your question. In fact, I do not know the best representation for the data. What's motivating my question is that I believe a continuous and smooth function will be a better representation (however imperfect) than a bar chart. And I want such a smooth function because, in the course of some data imputation, I need a representation that can deal with fractional year amounts. I believe (though I am willing to be shown wrong) that if all the pieces of g should be quadratics, then there is one and only one solution for any given series. Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: @Zéychin: Thanks for your comment. You are using different letters than I used, but if I adopt your lettering, really I want to find h(x). In fact, I already know H(x,x+1) where x and y are integers in the domain [1983, 1990) -- those are the values in the table. What I want is a smooth function h(x) which also has the same values of H(x,x+1) for all x in [1983,1990).

Comment: I think you're trying to make it prettier, but that often results in the loss of informativity. In this case, I don't see what's wrong about a bar chart [like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/timeline/15833eb5fd215305b5408fa1b9db622f.png)

Comment: @WorldSEnder: Thanks for your help. I agree that there is nothing wrong with a bar chart for representing data. I am not actually looking to *display* my hoped-for function in any sort of diagram, so informativity is not a metric I am worried about in this case. I want the smooth function as a way to do some data imputation which can account for fractional years (which is another story entirely). Very sorry if my question created a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the integral of your curve to go through a specific set of points, defined by the cumulative totals, so...

Interpolate between the cumulative totals to get an integral curve, and then
take the derivative of that to get the function you're looking for.

Since you want your function to be "continuous and smooth", i.e., C1-continuous, the integral curve you interpolate needs to be C2-continuous, i.e., it has to have continuous first and second derivatives.  You can use polynomial interpolation, sinc interpolation, splines of sufficient degree, etc.

Using "natural" cubic splines to interpolate the integral will give you a piece-wise quadratic derivative that seems to satisfy all your requirements.

There's a pretty good description of the natural cubic splines here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicSpline.html

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to transform discrete data into a continuous representation, I would recommend looking up [Kernel Density Estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). KDE essentially models each data point as a (usually) Gaussian distribution and sums up the distribution, resulting in a smooth continuous distribution. [This blog](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/) does a very thorough treatment of KDE using the SciPy module.

One of the downsides of KDE is that it does not provide an analytic solution. If that is your goal, I would recommend looking up [polynomial regression](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html).

Comment: Thank you for this thought. I have considered KDE, but the reason I would like to find a different solution in this case is because KDE does not preserve the yearly totals exactly, and because those yearly totals -- H(x,x+1) for integer x in [1983,1990), to use @Zéychin 's notation above -- are the only thing I know for sure, I want to maintain them exactly. I will look more into polynomial regression, but what I would ideally like is a piecewise function, one piece per year, rather than a single polynomial of arbitrary degree which minimizes squared error. Thanks again for your suggestions!